# PHP (strpos) Empty delimiter, but not empty

Tags: php, strpos

I've got a `$url` (wich I get with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and a `$menu`, that contains the Links from the web.

When I do: `if(strpos($url, $menu) !== false)` to know if the URL and the Link contains at least `xxx.php` (because can have `xxx.php?aaaaaaa`), it throws me a warning of empty delimiter. I made an echo from both variables, and they are not empty at all.

My code goes something like this:

```
$menu = obtain_menu();
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //getting the url
$url = end(explode("/", $url)); //obtain the page (xxx.php)
for($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    $active = "";
    if(strpos($url, $menu[$i]['Link']) !== false)
        $active = "active";
}
```

If I'm wrong I would appreciate you to teach me where and how.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you got?

Comment: Also the `$url` manipulation is only needed once. Why did you put it inside the loop?

Comment: You are right, Jon, just changed it right now.

Comment: In addition: `end()` will emit an `E_STRICT` warning when used like that -- to correct that, use an intermediate variable: `$x = explode(...); $url = end($x);`. Another option (one-liner): `$url = array_slice(explode(...), -1)[0];` but this needs PHP 5.4.

Comment: @Jon Or just `basename($url)`.

Comment: The error is this one: `Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in C:\wamp\www\XXX\ZZZ\header.php on line 79`
I tried adding echo's inside the for, and they are not empty at all, $url and $menu.

Comment: If you `var_dump($menu[$i]);` above the strpos if statement, check the array and make sure the key is correct (ie capital L)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP thanks, I think I've found it. doing var_dump I found that some links are "" empty, so it's right.
Thanks for it! Now is working properly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ardilla I've posted my comment as an answer so this question can be marked completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `var_dump($menu[$i]);` above the strpos if statement and check the array